# Why is Microsoft Access ADP file claiming my query is misspelled, with a 1 at the end of the query?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 database file of type ADP (which can be compiled to an ADE file). This front-end application interacts with a Microsoft SQL Server in the backend. This application works fine in the current environment, but is having trouble in a new environment.

In the new environment, the datasheet-type form we use loads correctly. The query in the form RecordSource is:

> SELECT t1.columnone, t2.columntwo
> FROM tableone t1
> INNER JOIN tabletwo t2 ON t2.columntwo = t1.columntwo
> WHERE t1.condition = 'test'

This will then fail, when trying to use the MS Access form to add a new record to existing records.  The error is:

> 'SELECT t1.columnone, t2.columntwo FROM tableone t1 INNER JOIN tabletwo t2 ON t2.columntwo = t1.columntwo WHERE t1.condition = 'test'**1**'@* You misspelled the object name.  Check for missing
> underscores (_) or other punctuation, and make sure you didn't enter
> leading spaces. * You tried to open a linked table, but the file
> containing

Upon closer inspection, we can see that the number 1 has been erroneously added to the end of the query, but can confirm that the number 1 doesn't appear anywhere in the source code, so it is unclear why it is being added at runtime.

We can confirm that the MS Access version is exactly same between versions and the SQL Server database is also the same.

Based on research, we tried removing the dbo prefix from MS Access code, so that the code just shows tablename in queries (and no dbo. prefix). However, the issue persists.

EDIT: Symptoms are the same as this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676293/access-2010-adp-appending-a-1-to-the-end-of-object-names, however the solution in that case is not relevant here (there is not multiple copies of MS Office/Access installed).

Comment: The error you're receiving isn't a database error, rather it sounds like it's generated from MS Access. Additionally, `condition1` sounds like a generic object name given by MS Access as well, for what's probably a placeholder used in the query. This would have nothing to do with qualifying your table names with their correlating schema name (`dbo`) and in general you should specify the schema. You would have to find where MS Access is generating that object name and correct it. Perhaps MS Access has some kind of global Find function.

Comment: The query itself is in the RecordSource for the form.  For some reason, it is just adding 1 at the end, and reporting it in the error message.

Comment: Yea again I'm sure it's something MS Access is doing. Does your `table` have a column named `condition`?

Comment: J.D. yes, the table has a column named condition.  Everything about the query is correct in the source, and the same query works fine when run directly in MS Sql Server Management Studio.  The same query also works correctly inside MS Access in the original environment.  There's just something about this new environment that is stumping me.  I was just curious if anybody else had run accross this, and what they did to narrow it down...

Comment: Interesting. Maybe `condition` is some sort of keyword in MS Access that it's updating to enumerate the name of. Bit of a stretch, but any chance you can update the query to say `... where columntwo = someOtherColumn` just to rule out my theory?

Comment: I've done some more tests, and it appears to be a problem for any RecordSource query that uses a join between multiple tables.  A RecordSource using a single table seems to work fine, without error.  I've updated the description above to show a relevent multi-table query which fails in the new environment.